# Jqgrid can Edit but not Add

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid

I have my grid running and I can EDIT data but I cannot ADD new rows of data. When I submit the add form nothing happens and I get nothing back on my PHPMyAdmin page to show that the grid is hit the database with the INSERT statement.

Here is my Edit code.

```
    <?php

$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; 
$dbpass = "*****"; 
$dbname = "******"; 

// connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");

//$id = "'".$_POST['id']."'";
$unit = "'".$_POST['unit_id']."'";
$div = "'".$_POST['div_id']."'";
$titleorg = "'".$_POST['title_org']."'";
$shortdesc = "'".$_POST['short_desc']."'";
$longdesc = "'".$_POST['long_desc']."'";
$unitdesc = "'".$_POST['unit_desc']."'";
$enabled = "'".$_POST['avail_ind']."'";
$active = "'Y'";


switch($_POST['oper'])
{
    case "add":
        $query = "INSERT INTO depunits (unit_id, div_id, title_org, short_desc, long_desc, unit_desc, avail_ind,active_ind) values ($div,$unit,$titleorg,$shortdesc,$longdesc,$unitdesc,$enabled,$active)";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    break;

    case "edit":
        $query = "UPDATE depunits SET unit_id=$unit,div_id=$div,title_org=$titleorg,short_desc=$shortdesc,long_desc=$longdesc,unit_desc=$unitdesc,avail_ind=$enabled where unit_id=$unit";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
    break;
}

?>
```

Comment: Use PDO or sanitize your input

Comment: mysqli supports parametrized queries, why aren't you using them?

Comment: I'll be 100% honest, I'm not sure what that is or how to use it. Any help would be amazing.